# Como puedo cambiar los argumentos al compilador de c++ en vscode?

Tags: c++, socket

necesito agregar la opcion -lws2_32 al g++ y no se por donde se hace en vscode, si hay algun #pragma que haga eso mucho mejor

```cpp
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <bits/stdtr1c++.h>
#define ll long long
using namespace std;
#define MAXN 1000000

int main()
{
    auto sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0); // da error undefined reference to __imp_socket
}
```

se agradece mucho mucho una ayudita

Answer (score 0):

Abrí las configuraciones de C/C++.

[image: imagen de la documentación]

Dentro de las configuraciones podes agregar los parámetros que necesites en la sección **Compiler arguments**.

[image: imagen de la documentación]

[Más información](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw#_cc-configurations).

Comment: muchas gracias amigo